# How to declare a weak property with getter setter and backing variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

After I refactored some code, I have this property:

```
@objc public weak var output: ELGameFramePresenterOutput?
```

Due to some architecture decisions - I have to actually make it of type `ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput` (which is a subclass of `ELGameFramePresenterOutput`).

Note that `var output: ELGameFramePresenterOutput?` is coming from a protocol my class implements. That protocol is created in Objective-C and cannot simply replace the type of that property with a subclass (Although it works fine in Objective-C).

Would this be the correct way to return a Subclass Type while also conforming to the protocol?

```
private weak var _output: ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput?

@objc public weak var output: ELGameFramePresenterOutput? {
    get {
        return _output
    }
    set {
        _output = newValue as? ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Additional info:

**ELGameFramePresenterIO.m**

```
@protocol ELGameFramePresenterInput <NSObject>

- (NSString *)identifier;
- (void)setView:(id<ELGameFrameViewInput>)view;

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<ELGameFramePresenterDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<ELGameFramePresenterOutput> output;
@property(nonatomic) ELGameInfoViewController *gameInfoController;

@end

@protocol ELGameFramePresenterOutput <NSObject>

- (void)requestGameId:(NSInteger)gameId;
- (void)requestNextSubcategory;

- (void)gameFramePresenter:(id<ELGameFramePresenterInput>)presenter
           didCompleteGame:(ELStudyGameInfo *)game;

- (id<ELGameCompletionPresenter>)completionPresenterForGameFramePresenter:(id<ELGameFramePresenterInput>)presenter;

@end
```

**ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterIO.swift**

```
@objc public protocol ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput: ELGameFramePresenterOutput {}
```

So initially I had an Objective-C class ELPracticeGameFlowPresenter that would implement ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterInput (which inherits from ELGameFramePresenterInput) protocol, and that protocol was containing this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<ELGameFramePresenterOutput> output;
```

But in the actual implementation contained that property with a different type:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput> output;
```

In Objective-C it's fine apparently to use a different type for that property, but Swift says it doesn't much the protocol requirements. So I want to make sure everything remains same functionality wise.

FINAL EDIT:

I decided to use it like this:

```
private weak var _output: ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput?

@objc public weak var output: ELGameFramePresenterOutput? {
    get {
        return _output
    }
    set {
        _output = newValue as? ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the details of the protocol and its exact requirements? I'm actually surprised `public weak var output` is even allowed. `weak` only really makes sense in context of _persisted_ values. E.g. you can't pass an arguement to a parameter weakly. You'd pass it normally, with a strong reference, but it wouldn't matter because the reference would be short-lived, unlike a stored property.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander! I've added more to my question.

Comment: I would just add weak to _output. I think it will behave same as in Objective-C. My concern was if there would be any difference or issue if I use weak for output as well.

Comment: In earnest, I don't know how `weak` works on computed properties. For the stored prop, it should definitely be `weak`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no issue with your proposed Swift code. The use of `weak` on the computed property is a contract declaration that whatever value you pass in will not have a strong reference applied to it. Your code honors that contract by storing the value with a weak backing variable.

The only key difference between the Swift code and the Objective-C code is that the Swift code is stricter. If the assigned value doesn't actually conform to `ELPracticeGameFlowPresenterOutput` at runtime then `nil` is stored instead. While in the Objective-C code, you can actually store any arbitrary value at runtime. Of course this is one of the benefits of Swift over Objective-C. Swift lessens the opportunities for such runtime bugs.

If you were to declare `output` without `weak`, it might still work due to the `weak` private `_output` but your code would then present a public property that is `strong` when in reality the implementation would make it `weak`. This misleads the user of the code into thinking your class holds a strong reference when in fact it would not. Bugs would happen and they would be hard to find.

Comment: but would it make any difference if we add weak to both properties? Seems that as long as one of them is set as weak - it should be no issue at all.

Comment: Both need to be weak as you show in your question. The weak stored property (backing variable) must be weak. The computed property should be weak to designate the contract of the property.

Comment: @ppalancica I was right, `weak` doesn't do anything on computed properties. https://forums.swift.org/t/can-we-forbid-weak-keyword-for-computed-properties/19811/14 The weakness is an attribute of the _storage_, not the reference. The important part is that the stored property is weak (so it doesn't form a strong retain cycle). It doesn't matter if the computed property is `weak` or not, because it's only making an ephemeral strong reference that will disappear near-instantly.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, functionally it doesn't matter in this case but the use of `weak` on the public property is important to indicate the intent.

Comment: @HangarRash Makes sense!